# What does the head: property do on Page{} in qml?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have an app that I am trying to get the toolbar in the header to work. In the documentation I've noticed a property called `head` that seems to create and add items to the header toolbar.

What is the difference between this and the `toolbaritems`?

Also, related, in trying to use this head property, I get the error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "head" (similar to question [Why am I getting the error “Cannot assign to non-existent property ”head"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511455/why-am-i-getting-the-error-cannot-assign-to-non-existent-property-head))

Which one is the correct (or better) way?

Thank you

Randy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toolbaritems` has been deprecated in `Ubuntu.Components 1.1`, so its use is strongly discouraged. It is maintained for backward compatibility, but the right way to add items to the header toolbar is now using `head.actions`.

The main difference between `head.actions` and `toolbaritems` is that you don't need anymore to add `ToolbarButton` items and then set their `action` property. All you need with `head.actions` is to specify a list of actions and then they will be automatically shown according to [Ubuntu Touch patterns](http://design.canonical.com/2014/03/new-apps-header/).

An example that shows how to use `head` property is the following (from [official documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.Page/)):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

MainView {
     width: units.gu(48)
     height: units.gu(60)
     Page {
         title: i18n.tr("Example page")
         Label {
             anchors.centerIn: parent
             text: i18n.tr("Hello world!")
        }
        head.actions: [
             Action {
                 iconName: "search"
                 text: i18n.tr("Search")
             },
             Action {
                 iconName: "contacts"
                 text: i18n.tr("Contacts")
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

There are some other useful settings for `PageHead` (e.g. custom `Item` to show instead of the title), so I'd suggest you to take a look at this [page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.PageHeadConfiguration/).

If you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, these new APIs are not available, due to their dependence on Qt 5.3. You can solve this issue following this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511455/why-am-i-getting-the-error-cannot-assign-to-non-existent-property-head/515615#515615) .

Comment: This is good info, thanks. This answers my question.